# When to use WCF REST and WEB API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest

I am little confused about these two technologies ie **WCF REST** and **asp.net WEB API**. Is there any difference between these two? When should use one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

> I am little confused about these two technologies ie WCF REST and asp.net WEB API. Is there any difference between these two?

Yes.  Both are a means to providing REST-style services however the competing technologies **are not created equal**.

WCF REST naturally comes from the WCF world which is originally SOAP.  WCF REST changes that by providing a rudimentary JSON payload instead of SOAP.  However WCF REST is missing certain features and Microsoft has said that newer REST features will only make its way into ASP.NET Web API.

Unlike WCF REST, ASP.NET Web API has been designed from the ground up for REST-style JSON services.

MSDN:

> Although WCF provides some support for writing REST-style services, **the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete** and **all future REST feature improvements will be made in ASP.NET Web API**. If you have an existing WCF service and you want to expose additional REST endpoints, use WCF and the WebHttpBinding. - [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx)

OP:

> When should use one over the other?

- If your intent is to create SOAP services, or you have an **existing WCF service**, use WCF with a JSON encoding endpoint.
- If your intent is to create REST services, particularly in a **new application**,  then use ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: @MicikyD thanks for the answer, Can you please explain which are REST features not supported in WCF REST

Comment: _"[More suitable for access from various browsers, mobile devices etc enabling wide reach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx)"_.  WCF REST not so much.  WCF doesn't support WebSockets; or JQuery; can't be integrated with SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do for choose one of them

Basically with the WCF you can create service based applications
but with ASP.NET Web Api you can create Restful services based on Http or Https.

Comment: My question is related to WCF REST and asp.net WEB API not regular wcf service.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Also `but with ASP.NET Web Api you can create Restful services based on Http or Https` can be applied to WCF REST

Answer (score 0):

REST and WCF are the meanings from different worlds :) REST is a specification (in other words the set of conventions) for developing the web-services. REST doesn't depends on some special technology / platform / framework or language. WCF is Microsoft approach for web-services, natively predifined to develope SOAP-services, which are based on RPC-architecture. RPC (remote procedure call) is an approach to develope web-services as a set of methods with parameters, which are doing some work. REST is more HTTP-oriented and the main concept is to operate with some entities (Representational State Transfer) and perform actions to this entities, but not just call some methods. It is possible to build some REST-service using WCF technology, but in my opinion, WCF isn't a good way for this goal.

Comment: Can you please throw some light on why WCF is not a good choice for REST service?

Comment: The question is not about **WCF vs REST** but rather _"WCF REST and WEB API"_